# How do I fix: check and repair file system (ntfs) on /Dev/sda3

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

It all started when I installed Ubuntu 18.04, then when I restart it sends me grub rescue, I can't access Windows 10 nor Ubuntu 18.04, I did a live USB and found out, the following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support: ntfs-3g/ntfaprogs,I am not an expert at this but I don't know if it's seriously bad, any help will do, THANKS